# Getting NULL with ViewPager FindByViewID(R.id)

Tags: java, android-studio

I am going crazy, I tried to use ViewPager, CarouselView, ImageCarousel, ImageSlider and others and I keep having the same issue:
`mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain); R.id.viewPagerMain has value but nothing gets assigned to "mViewPager".`

I have watched several videos, read several explanations and I can´t notice any difference.
I thought that maybe I need to create a class specific for the ViewPager and nothing more...

I have not created a carousel before, and I really do not understand what the problem is.

What am I doing wrong?? Please help.
Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Vistas.Logins.Login_activity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                android:background="@color/strongblue"
                android:contentDescription="@string/wali"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/bienvenido2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/bienvenido2"
                    android:textColor="@color/WaliBlue"
                    android:textSize="40sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/usuariorecordado"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/usuariovariable"
                        android:textColor="@color/WaliBlue"
                        android:textSize="40sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bienvenido2final"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/bienvenido2final"
                        android:textColor="@color/WaliBlue"
                        android:textSize="40sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/mano_ico" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/iniciasesion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:text="@string/iniciasesion"
                    android:textColor="@color/walilog"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="350dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
                    app:passwordToggleTint="@color/green">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="48sp"
                        android:autofillHints=""
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
                        android:hint="@string/password"
                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
                    android:id="@+id/recordarSesion"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="@string/recordarSesion"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey"
                    app:switchPadding="15dp"
                    app:thumbTint="@drawable/newthumb_switch" />

                <!-- <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/recordarSesion"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/toggle_on" />

                    Temporal porque irá un toggle-->


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/botoniniciar"
                    android:layout_width="250dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/boton_ripple"
                    android:text="@string/botoniniciar"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nousuario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/nousuario"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/otracuenta"
                    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="48dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:text="@string/otracuenta"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/walilog"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/azulrey"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/link"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:text="@string/link"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:drawableLeftCompat="@drawable/web"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/ayuda"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="48dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="-30dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="@string/ayuda"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:drawableStartCompat="@drawable/ayuda"
                        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

        <RelativeLayout

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/dimBackground"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible">

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/loadingPanel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    // Context object
    Context context;

    // Array of images
    int[] images;

    // Layout Inflater
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;


    // Viewpager Constructor
    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] images) {
        this.context = context;
        this.images = images;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // return the number of images
        return images.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, final int position) {

        // inflating the item
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.carrusel_inicio, container, false);

        // referencing the image view from the item.xml file
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);

        // setting the image in the imageView
        imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

        // Adding the View
        Objects.requireNonNull(container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {

        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

```
public class Login_recordarUsuario extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText password;
    Button botoniniciar,otracuenta,ayuda;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    public ProgressBar loadingPanel;
    TextView iniciasesion,bienvenido2,link,nousuario,bienvenido2final,usuariorecordado;
    SwitchCompat recordarSesion;
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.walilogin, R.drawable.wall_e, R.drawable.walle};
    ViewPagerAdapter mViewPagerAdapter;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login_recordar_usuario);

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        boolean connected = (Objects.requireNonNull(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                Objects.requireNonNull(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);

            String ubicacion = "Tipografia/GalanoGrotesqueAlt-Regular.ttf";
            String ubicacion2 = "Tipografia/GalanoGrotesqueDEMO-Bold.ttf";
            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(Login_recordarUsuario.this.getAssets(), ubicacion); //Inicia sesión para...
            Typeface tf2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(Login_recordarUsuario.this.getAssets(), ubicacion2); // Bienvenido

            recordarSesion = findViewById(R.id.recordarSesion);

            password = findViewById(R.id.password);
            botoniniciar = findViewById(R.id.botoniniciar);
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_recordarUsuario.this);
            loadingPanel = findViewById(R.id.loadingPanel);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Iniciando sesión...");
            iniciasesion = findViewById(R.id.iniciasesion);
            bienvenido2 = findViewById(R.id.bienvenido2);
            link = findViewById(R.id.link);
            nousuario = findViewById(R.id.nousuario);
            otracuenta = findViewById(R.id.otracuenta);
            usuariorecordado = findViewById(R.id.usuariorecordado);
            bienvenido2final = findViewById(R.id.bienvenido2final);
            ayuda = findViewById(R.id.ayuda);

        // Initializing the ViewPager Object
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);

        // Initializing the ViewPagerAdapter
        mViewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(Login_recordarUsuario.this, images);

        // Adding the Adapter to the ViewPager
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);

//.... code Continues
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue, thank you.

I took the Pager outside of the scroll view. Also, I had another layout V28 created by the IDE and I didn´t noticed it, i had to modify that one as well.